# Export handler function for AWS Lambda with serverless framework

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have created a **handler function** which should be accessible via API Gateway (getRecommendation) in a **serverless** setup

So far I had made this function available via

```
module.exports.getRecommendation = async (event) => {
        // executed code
}
```

This **works just fine**

For testing purposes I wanted to make this function accessible also for Jest and defined a **different export statement** which should work in the same way from my point of view:

```
module.exports  = getRecommendation

async function getRecommendation (event) {
       //executed code
}
```

However, when I run **sls offline** and try to send data to the endpoint via **Postman**, I get the **error** message that

`handler 'getRecommendation' in E:\... is not a function`

As I would **expect** the both statements to behave similar I was wondering if you could give me a **hint what I'm missing**

Thanks

Comment: In the first code you set the `getRecommendation` property of `module.exports` to a function. In your second code you set the `exports` property of `module` to a function. Try `module.exports.getRecommendation  = getRecommendation`

Comment: Thank you for helping me out - this was the adjustment which was needed. Kind regards